# Devise route helpers are not known during tests any more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) route helpers methods are not recognized in my Ruby functional tests.

For instance, my application's layout contains a call to `edit_admin_registration_path` (since my device model is Admin) and I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `edit_admin_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff332374038>:0x007ff330d54988>
```

when running:

```
rake test:functionals TEST=test/functional/my_controller_test.rb
```

I think I get this problem since upgrading to Rails 3.2.15. Any idea why? (devise version is 3.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have this route helper by:

   rake routes
2. Seems like similar discusion [Rails Can't find route in Functional Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143750/rails-cant-find-route-in-functional-test)